# The right way of using QIODevice::readLine()

Tags: qt

I'm trying to use `QIODevice::readLine()`. I have looked at the two versions -- one returning `QByteArray`:

```
QByteArray buffer = iodevice->readLine()
```

and one reading to char* buffer:

```
char buffer[SIZE];
qint64 used;
used = iodevice->readline(buffer, SIZE);
```

I need to read a line, detect errors and manipulate it as QString.

Which of these two overloaded versions should I use to make it simple and efficient?

What I know so far:

- The QByteArray version has a problem with not being able to detect read errors. The memory might be allocated back and forth in the `=` operator
- char* version lets me detect read errors, but it forces me to limit the size of data I read and it's harder to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better way, it depends on the application I guess. You can simply profile the two if performance of this operation is critical for your application.

Consider that by using the QByteArray you're not allocating the memory "back and forth". QByteArray implements implicit sharing, so it is fast and efficient to use the operator =. Exactly the same as the char*, but simpler maybe.

QString has both the ctor with the QByteArray and the char*, so that is exactly the same.

EDIT: To clarify the point about copies when QByteArray is returned by value consider that yes, two objects might be created, but only shallow copies are made. This is therefore efficient. You might want to read [this](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html) which is very important. Also, consider having a [closer look](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/io/qiodevice.cpp) :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it made me realize that performance isn't that critical here :-)
Just a little side question: returning QByteArray causes allocation anyway, since inside the function readLine (before returning) there must be two QByteArrays created (one that will be returned, and one outside the function scope that will be holding the value after readLine returns, right?

Comment: I added some details to the answer. Hope that answers your question.